# Does SPSS adjust chi squared tests for weighted samples?

Tags: statistics, spss, chi-squared, weighting

In SPSS, you can adjust summary statistics for stratified samples using
`Weight by ...`, and it allows you to then do a chi-squared test. I found a lot of examples of people doing a chi-squared like this, but nobody mentioning whether SPSS actually accounts for this in the chi square calculation.

**Does standard SPSS adjust the chi squared test of independence for the stratified sample after using** `Weight by ...`**?**

The R "survey" package uses [Rao-Scott correction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf). Similarily, [SAS has a Rao-Scott Chi-square test](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyfreq_a0000000221.htm).
I'm aware of the [SPSS complex surveys extension](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/spss-complex-samples) - while I'd be curious how well that one works, here I'm specifically interested in whether base SPSS does this correctly.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is *No*. Base SPSS does not adjust standard errors for stratified samples.**

All calculations in SPSS on weighted samples that use the standard error (p-values, confidence intervals, ...) will be **wrong** without the Complex Surveys extension.

---

Confimed by [IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21480902), [UCLA](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/what-types-of-weights-do-sas-stata-and-spss-support/), [PARE](https://pareonline.net/pdf/v16n12.pdf) and [Thomas Lumley](https://twitter.com/tslumley/status/1097630029683421184).

All sources [recommended](https://twitter.com/tslumley/status/1097643887294742528) by Thomas Lumley.